# Bad exercise statement

Tags: c, algorithm

Given the problem:

[image]

The statement is a bit ambiguous. I don't really understand what they want.
I can display the desired result using just a regular `for loop`:

```
int step = 0
for(int i = 1; i < m + 1; i++)
{
    if(i != p)
    {
        printf("(%d, %d)", step, i);
        step++;
    }
}
```

Is this what they really want? I see that they are talking about linear time, so I think it can't be that easy? Am I supposed to build the vector that they are talking about, and then delete it?

Comment: My understanding is that the steps need to follow the patterm  (1,..)  (2,..) (2,..) (3,..) (3,..), (3,..) (3,..) (4,..) etc. They may also want to see a data structure that you are actually 'deleting' from, and respecting existing deletions..

Comment: No, that's clearly not what the question asks for. The important thing in this question is the manner in which elements are deleted from the vector; printing the results is a minor part of the problem.

Comment: @greggo How would you approach it, can you give me a pseudo-code or a description of your solution?

Comment: Make notes stepping through what is wanted, then think about code.

Comment: Think of 3 nested  loops: (1) per step (2) per item deleted in the step (3) looking for an item to delete. The last two loops could be done as one loop instead. And there's more than one way to do that, some are not O(m).

Comment: On the question itself: by clearly telling you the existing pattern of deleted items in the vector *and* telling you that the deleted items contain 'X', the question doesn't make it clear how you are to detect already-deleted items - via their content ('X'), or their position. Likewise, why tell you the values of the non-deleted entries? Does that mean you can assume that they have those values, and don't need to read them? Or is that a trap?  This sort of thing makes it a dubious-quality question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (compile with `gcc test.c -lm`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int n = 4;
    int m = (int)pow(2,n);
    int p = 5;

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = (int)pow(2,i-1); j < ((int)pow(2,i)); j++)
        {
            if(j == p) {
                continue;
            }
            printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
            // remove vector[j]
            if((j == (m-1)) && (m != p)) {
                printf("%d, %d\n", i, m);
                // remove vector[m]
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run result  `n=3, p=5`:

```
1, 1
2, 2
2, 3
3, 4
3, 6
3, 7
3, 8
```

Run result `n=4, p=5`:

```
1, 1
2, 2
2, 3
3, 4
3, 6
3, 7
4, 8
4, 9
4, 10
4, 11
4, 12
4, 13
4, 14
4, 15
4, 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write the full code. Let me make it simple:

- It should delete every element of the array.
- By the end of the loop your program should print out the step and one of the numbers that were deleted, into the format `(k, q)` where `k` is the step you are on, and `q` is one of the elements you had deleted .
- Every time you delete an element you can change it by `X`.
- You also need to remember the algorithm they are telling you to use and the *"rules of the game"*, for example: `n` should be positive and an integer.

And if you do not understand the algorithm, just try to put the idea on a paper:

When I put `n = 1`, I should delete one element from the array. When `n = 2`, 2 elements, When `n = 3` it should delete 4 elements , `n = 4` it deletes 8 element, etc.

As we can see, it is pretty simple because it goes like a geometric progression.